# Saving Information - Swing Shapes

Tags: java, swing, variables, object, events

I want to be able to store a shape created using a graphics object as a variable, however the output is of type void and casting it doesn't work.

At the moment I am only able to use a Graphics reference using the paintComponent method. However I want to be able to store a shape (which happens to be of type void) as an instance variable of type Graphic...

Consider the following:

```
test class{
      Graphics instanceOfGraphics;

      public void createShape(Graphics g1){
             g1.setPaint(new Color(255, 0, 0));
             instanceOfGraphics = g1.fillOval(//xPosition, //yPosition,
                                              //width, //height);

             }
          }
```

The source code above did not work, because the return type of the fillOval method is void, even when I try to cast the silent return value it did not work.

How would I go about saving/storing the created shape as a variable.

In the future I would like to be able to register a Listener on the Shape and allow my created shape to be an event source.

Comment: I hope you are aware that 1) void means you are not returning anything 2) You are updating g1 reference, so wherever you called createShape(...) you have access to g1.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what would you recommend I change the title to.

Comment: @Nambari Yes I am aware void means you are not returning anything, but how would I save the Oval, so that in the future I could use it as an event source.

Comment: Please check answer below, and consider adding `"use it as an event source"` to your question, as that changes the answer some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The source code above did not work, because the return type of the fillOval method is void, even when I try to cast the silent return value it did not work.

You're looking at storing an *effect* which is impossible, and what you want to do is store *data*. If you want to store oval type data, simply use an `Ellipse2D` field and store the information there.

```
Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(//xPosition, //yPosition,
                                          //width, //height);
```

then draw it with your Graphics2D object within paintComponent.

Swing has the useful Shape interface which has been implemented into several concrete classes that could serve your purpose well.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
   private Map<Shape, Color> shapeColorMap = new HashMap<>();

   public GraphicsEg() {
      Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, 30, 30);
      shapeColorMap.put(shape, Color.RED);
      shapes.add(shape);

      shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(140, 140, 200, 200);
      shapeColorMap.put(shape, Color.BLUE);
      shapes.add(shape);

      shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(200, 200, 80, 80, 10, 10);
      shapeColorMap.put(shape, Color.GREEN);
      shapes.add(shape);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      for (Shape shape : shapes) {
         Color color = shapeColorMap.get(shape);
         g2.setColor(color);
         g2.fill(shape);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GraphicsEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new GraphicsEg());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Here several different Shapes (Ellipse2D, Rectangle2D, RoundRectangle2D) are stored in an ArrayList of Shape objects, and then these are drawn within the JPanel's paintComponent method after first casting the Graphics object into a Graphics2D. I've also added a `HashMap<Shape, Color>` to allow easy association of a Shape with a Color.

Also you state in comment that,

> use it as an event source

which brings another useful feature about all classes that implement Shape -- they have a `contains(...)` method that if used well with a MouseListener will allow you to easily see if a mouse clicked inside of one of your shapes.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicsEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final Color SELECTED_COLOR = Color.RED;
   private static final Stroke SELECTED_STROKE = new BasicStroke(8f);
   private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
   private Map<Shape, Color> shapeColorMap = new HashMap<>();
   private Shape selectedShape = null;

   public GraphicsEg() {
      Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, 90, 90);
      shapeColorMap.put(shape, Color.GRAY);
      shapes.add(shape);

      shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(140, 140, 200, 200);
      shapeColorMap.put(shape, Color.BLUE);
      shapes.add(shape);

      shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(200, 200, 80, 80, 10, 10);
      shapeColorMap.put(shape, Color.GREEN);
      shapes.add(shape);

      addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      for (Shape shape : shapes) {
         Color color = shapeColorMap.get(shape);
         g2.setColor(color);
         g2.fill(shape);
      }

      if (selectedShape != null) {
         Graphics2D newG2 = (Graphics2D) g2.create();
         newG2.setColor(SELECTED_COLOR);
         newG2.setStroke(SELECTED_STROKE);
         newG2.draw(selectedShape);
         newG2.dispose(); // because this is a created Graphics object
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         for (int i = shapes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (shapes.get(i).contains(e.getPoint())) {
               selectedShape = shapes.get(i);
               repaint();
               return;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GraphicsEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new GraphicsEg());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I have always wondered why shape doesn't have a color property. Seems so natural.