# Add functionality to Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics

This is my code, I want to add functionality to the Rect that I made, like when you click on it, a window pops up

```
public class codetwo extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(110,110, 120, 120);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        codetwo cd = new codetwo(); 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        frame.add(cd);
        frame.setSize(440,350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) class names should start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions. 2) add a MouseListener to the panel. 3) in the mouseClicked event check if the mouse click point is contained in the rectangle that you painted.

Comment: [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), e.g. a **web search** for [`java graphics mouse click`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+graphics+mouse+click).

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190103/522444)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Mouselistener for this.

```
public class codetwo extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(110,110, 120, 120);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        codetwo cd = new codetwo(); 
cd.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if  (e.getX() >= 110 && e.getX() <= 230 && e.getY() >= 110 && e.getY() <= 230) { 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(cd, "Some one clicked here ?", "Listening", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        frame.add(cd);
        frame.setSize(440,350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```