# I want to redraw my oval as the mouse enters it

Tags: java, swing, math, graphics

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        m_View = new View(m_Mod);
        int maxY = m_Mod.y1 + m_Mod.oheight;
        int maxX = m_Mod.x1 + m_Mod.owidth;
        if (x > m_Mod.x1 & x < maxX & y > m_Mod.y1 & x < maxY) {
            Graphics g = m_Mod.frame.getGraphics();
            m_View.draw(g);
            System.out.print("IM KREIS");
        }
    }
```

Somehow my math does not work here. I want to redraw my oval as soon as the mouse enters it. So my graphics object "g" is my oval here. `m_Mod.x1 / M_Mod.y1`  is x and y of my oval and `m_Mod.width / m_Mod.heigth`  are width and heigth of my oval.

Comment: How did you come up with `x > m_Mod.x1 & x < maxX & y > m_Mod.y1 & x < maxY`?

Comment: With this math I want to check if the mouse is inside my oval.

Comment: Don't do `m_Mod.frame.getGraphics();`, this is not how painting works in Swing

Comment: Swing's `Shape`s API can do hit detection

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you elaborate on that shape's API? How do I use it?

Comment: [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html)

Comment: Ellipse2D is a class derived from the Shape interface (as @MadProgrammer suggests that you use above), and it has a `contains(...)` method that can accept a Point (or Point2D). If you add a MouseMotionListener to your JPanel that does the drawing, then you can use this method to check if the mouse's position is inside the oval or not.

Comment: Thank you I will rewrite my program that way then.

Comment: In the MouseMotionListener (added to the drawing JPanel), check in the `mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)` method override if the mouse point (obtained from `MouseEvent#getPoint()`) is inside of your oval, and if so, set a boolean field to true, otherwise to false, and call `repaint()`. In your drawing JPanel's paintComponent method, use the state of this same boolean to determine if you fill the oval or not. There is no need for any fancy math at all. Also, don't forget to call the `paintComponent`'s super method in your own JPanel's override method.

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190103/522444)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the key to a solution is to:

- Do all drawing, all graphics and mouse listening within a single drawing JPanel
- To specifically draw within the JPanel's paintComponent method override
- To give your GUI a boolean field that is set to true
- To use an Ellipse2D object to define your oval
- To add a MouseMotionListener to the drawing JPanel
- Within this MouseMotionListener, check if the mouse point is within the ellipse
- Then set the boolean field with this result and call `repaint()`
- The paintComponent method will then determine what to draw based on the state of the boolean

For example, in the code below I have an Ellise2D field,

```
private Ellipse2D myOval = new Ellipse2D.Double(OVAL_X, OVAL_Y, OVAL_W, OVAL_H);
```

Then there is a boolean field, `private boolean insideOval = false;` that is set to false and that is changed within a MouseMotionListener to true if the mouse point is within the ellpise (here called `myOval`):

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {         
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        
        // true if the mouse point is within the oval. Otherwise false
        insideOval = myOval.contains(e.getPoint());
        
        // redraw the JPanel to draw the state of insideOval
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Then the paintComponent method will use the state of `insideOval` to determine what color to fill the oval with, an "active color" if the boolean is true and a clear color if not:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // does house-keeping drawing
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    // allow for smooth curves
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    
    // vary the oval fill color depending on the state of the insideOval field
    Color c = insideOval ? ACTIVE_COLOR : INACTIVE_COLOR;
    g2.setColor(c);
    
    // fill the oval
    g2.fill(myOval);
    
    // then draw the oval's border
    g2.setColor(OVAL_BORDER);
    g2.setStroke(BORDER_STROKE);
    g2.draw(myOval);
}
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    // main JPanel dimensions
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;
    
    // oval dimensions
    private static final double OVAL_X = 100;
    private static final double OVAL_Y = OVAL_X;
    private static final double OVAL_W = 400;
    private static final double OVAL_H = OVAL_W;
    
    // oval colors
    private static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0); // clear
    private static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.PINK;
    private static final Color OVAL_BORDER = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    
    // thickness of mouse border
    private static final Stroke BORDER_STROKE = new BasicStroke(4f);
    
    // Oval to draw and boolean to tell if mouse within the oval
    private Ellipse2D myOval = new Ellipse2D.Double(OVAL_X, OVAL_Y, OVAL_W, OVAL_H);
    private boolean insideOval = false;
    
    public DrawingPanel() {
        // add a mouse motion listener to this same drawing JPanel
        // and inside of it, check if the mouse point is inside or outside
        // of the oval.
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {         
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                
                // true if the mouse point is within the oval. Otherwise false
                insideOval = myOval.contains(e.getPoint());
                
                // redraw the JPanel to draw the state of insideOval
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return getPreferredSize();
        } else {
            return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // does house-keeping drawing
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        // allow for smooth curves
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        // vary the oval fill color depending on the state of the insideOval field
        Color c = insideOval ? ACTIVE_COLOR : INACTIVE_COLOR;
        g2.setColor(c);
        
        // fill the oval
        g2.fill(myOval);
        
        // then draw the oval's border
        g2.setColor(OVAL_BORDER);
        g2.setStroke(BORDER_STROKE);
        g2.draw(myOval);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            DrawingPanel mainPanel = new DrawingPanel();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you once again for your effort. <3